Unreadable Outlook Log Files
For a few weeks now we have two users who need to login into a "domain-login"-window upon starting outlook. We suspect our crm or ad fs to be responsible but can't know for sure. Therefore I've compared the outlook log .etl files of both users to compare the error event-IDs then compared the found IDs to mine to eliminate the unresponsible events not related to the issue (since I don't have the issue on my pc).
So here I am now with these three event IDs:

201
4042
4094

Unfortunately the Outlook Logs, when viewing in event viewer, have ZERO description. It's only "level" "date and time", "event id" and "task category", no description whatsoever.
Are those IDs known? What do they stand for? Or are they custom IDs from some old sysadmin and I'll have to look at the XML binary data and take a lucky guess what that event-log stands for?
Thank you for your help!
